# Convert ISO string to date time in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using mssql to convert string to date

I have two possible date formats in my application

Below are the possible formats

```
2021-07-14T6:08:29.829Z
2021-07-20T01:41:09.000000Z
```

I need to convert above formats like 2021-07-14 06:08:29

I tried with datetimeoffset but it is failing

```
Select CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,’2021-07-14T6:08:29.829Z’,127) AS DATETIME);
```

Above is failing for me, but it is working for below format

```
Select CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,’2021-07-20T01:08:29.829Z’,127) AS DATETIME);
```

Is there any way to convert both the formats ?

Comment: The above will fail because of your use of "smart quotes" (`’`). Use "normal" single quotes (`'`). After that, the reason it's failing is because your hour portion is only 1 digit; SQL Server is expecting 2. Specifically style `127` is string values in the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ` according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles).

Comment: Looks like it should be handled at the application side, because ISO-8601 extended time format is zero-padded hours, minutes, seconds. Something goes strange if the app produces this type of timestamp

Comment: Fix your application to generate **correct** ISO date strings.

Comment: See [ISO 8601: Times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) which confirms that the hour portion should be `[hh]`, where *"[hh] refers to a zero-padded hour between 00 and 23."* If you aren't using zero padded hours, the value is by definition not a ISO value.